# pandas add higher level column multiindex

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, multi-index

I am looking for a way to add a higher level column index in pandas.

I have a multiindexed pandas dataframe like this:

```
>>>df

   product       A         B         C
   sell_buy      sell buy  sell buy  sell buy 
group company
  1    Bank X     100  50   200  10    20  20
  2    Bank Y      20  40   150  40    30  20
  3    Bank Z     100  20    20  10    40  10
```

I want to add a higher level index in columns from `company`, and set a row index with the date of today (using something like `datetime.today()`)

```
   company       Bank X                        Bank Y                        Bank Z
   product       A         B         C         A         B         C         A         B         C
   sell_buy      sell buy  sell buy  sell buy  sell buy  sell buy  sell buy  sell buy  sell buy  sell buy
 2020-08-15       100  50   200  10    20  20    20  40   150  40    30  20   100  20    20  10    40  10
```

I tried several attempts, but I cannot figure out how to make it work...

```
pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.columns.levels, ['Bank X']])
pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.columns.levels, ['product']])
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: what is `print (df.index[:3].tolist())` ?

Comment: it's `[(1, 'Bank X'), (2, 'Bank Y'), (3, 'Bank Z')]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need in first step convert first level to `date` values and then reshape by [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html), [`MultiIndex.reorder_levels`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.reorder_levels.html) and [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
date = pd.Timestamp('today').floor('d')
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[date], df.index.get_level_values(1)])

df = df.unstack().reorder_levels([2,0,1], axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
print (df)
company    Bank X                        Bank Y                        Bank Z  \
product         A        B        C           A        B        C           A   
sell_buy      buy sell buy sell buy sell    buy sell buy sell buy sell    buy   
2020-08-15     50  100  10  200  20   20     40   20  40  150  20   30     20   

company                            
product           B        C       
sell_buy   sell buy sell buy sell  
2020-08-15  100  10   20  10   40
```

Comment: Thanks again @jezrael! It works perfectly for my needs. I need to practice more for handling these multi-indeces..